# Storing multi-word strings to a file

Tags: batch-file

I've recently been trying to make a program to simply store text to a file for later viewing, storing it as a .rar file for security against those who don't understand how to extract the text from the .rar (i.e. the less "techy" people)...

I have, however, encountered an error in the program that results in the `<word> not expected at this time` followed by the .exe closing when I input `add/<word> <word>...` (i.e. any multi-word string with spaces in between the words [`add/<word>`, however, does function properly]).

Is there a special rule that must be followed for storing multi-word strings to a .rar or a file in general (I do, however, know that there is a rule for creating/renaming folders/directories)?

The Program Segment:

```
:command

cls

set /p journal=<journal.rar

echo %journal%
echo.

set /p command=What would you like to do? 

cls
if %command%==exit exit
if %command%==help goto help
if %command%==delete echo START; > journal.rar
if %command:~0,4%==add/ echo "%journal%""%command:~4%;" > journal.rar
if %command:~0,5%==edit/ echo %journal:%command:~5%=%;" > journal.rar

goto command
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me. Your question is not clear. There are several confusing points in it, like "followed by the .exe closing" (which .exe is closing?), and the fact that your question is NOT related to .rar files in any way, nor to "storing multi-word strings". However, I can see the following points in it:

When a variable value is expanded with percent signs this way: `%command%` you must be aware that the variable is *first* expanded and *then* the resulting line is parsed. This mean that the value of the variable may introduce errors in the line. For example, in this line: `if %command%==exit exit`, if the value of command variable is `add/one two three`, then the line that is parsed is this: `if add/one two three==exit exit` that, of course, issue an error! (type `if /?` for further details).

The way to avoid this problem is enclosing both the variable and the comparison value in quotes; this way, if the value have several words with spaces, the whole value is grouped in the IF command for comparison purposes: `if "%command%" == "exit" exit`. This must be done in every IF command that use the value of the variable.

In the following line:

```
if %command:~0,5%==edit/ echo %journal:%command:~5%=%;" > journal.rar
```

you must be aware that the line is parsed from left to right; this means that you can not nest a %variable% expansion inside another one. The way to solve this problem is first complete a %normal% variable expansion, and then a !delayed! variable expansion that will take the previous expanded value. To do that, insert this line at beginning of your program:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

and change previous line by this one:

```
if "%command:~0,5%" == "edit/" echo !journal:%command:~5%=!;" > journal.rar
```

For further details, type `set /?` and carefully read the sections about "delayed expansion".

Comment: Seeing as how the only window I mentioned was CMD.exe and that it was running my batch program, I believe the .exe mentioned was clear. I am using .rar files to store the data; the program is not related to .rar in any way, and I never said it was; in the future do not assume the author meant something that wasn't said. Also, though I already knew of delayed expansion, with the amount of information I gave you, mentioning (lecturing) was irrelevant, though it would help people who don't already know, though the question was not related to it. Finally, you failed to answer my only question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that can accept multiple words:

```
set "command="
set /p "command=What would you like to do? "
cls
if /i "%command%"=="have lunch" goto :food
```